# Локализация приложение с использованием JSON

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, json.net

Имею приложение в котором по всюду используется `JSON` формат (сохраняю/получаю настройки из него; получаю данные с сервера для обновления приложения и обновления всех данных из него, ну и так далее). Я считаю это удобно, файл лежит в папочке и любой может изменить его, перевести итд.

Так вот, вопрос - как мне прикрутить систему перевода (весь текст приложение, все меню итд.) с возможностью выбора языка программы с использованием файлов `JSON`? 
Хочется, что бы в отдельной папке лежали файлы (к примеру `RU-ru.json`) и в них, в удобном виде строки перевода (`"Key": "Перевод"`). Нужно перевести как значения в коде, так и в `XAML`. В общем аналог локализации приложения с использованием ресурс. файлов, но только заместо `.resources.dll` файла (где находится языковая таблица) должен быть открытый `.json` файл.

Comment: сериализация json есть в С#
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr Как делать сериализацию/десериализацию я прекрасно знаю, вопрос в том - как грамотно перевести элементы приложение при помощи JSON файлов. К примеру вот статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256193/), где показывается как перевести нужные элементы при помощи файла ресурсов. Мне нужно тоже, но вместо файла ресурса - файл JSON.

Comment: А чем вам не угодила стандартная локализация, которая использует ресурсы `.resx`?

Comment: @sp7 Файлы `.resx` в последующем ведь собираются в `.dll` файл, который для обычного люда не удобен в плане перевода. Так же если приложение все построено на JSON, так почему бы не использовать `.json` и для перевода? Это скажем будет красиво смотреться в директории приложения и приятно в использовании. Так же у меня уже используется `.json` для перевода данных, которые выдает сервер (ибо он дает их в виде ключа `AA/BB/CC` и это надо переводить в понятный язык), но тут идет перевод при добавление значений в `List<>`. Так что раз там перевод через `.json`, значит и приложение надо через него.

Comment: json файл тоже не очень удобен для простого люда. почему бы тогда не сделать просто текстовый файл? что-то типа словаря. тоже будет "ключ: значение" и сразу понятно как сделать

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr Повторюсь - У меня **всё** приложение использует JSON формат. И настройки с него читаются и другой файл перевода, да и даже данные с сервера в формате JSON. Для людей, которые пользуются данной программой формат JSON не проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходима локализация объектов со строчными полями в JSON. Основная идея в том, чтобы сохранить пути к нужным файлам и использовать их на стадии компиляции. Достаточно одного файла, хранящего пути на ваши `.RU-ru.json`, `.EN-en.json`. А уже в них можете засунуть ссылки на остальные файлы JSON.

### Локализация

- Ручная - один JSON, где будет сохраняться выбор из перечня языков и заранее заданы пути к файлам локализации.
- Автоматизированная - один RESX, с нужными путями.

### Доступ как к ресурсам

Модификатор `x:static` здесь не помощник, т.к. работа с JSON предполагает работу не со статическими объектами. Для этих целей используйте привязки `code-behind`.

---

Возможные решения для ASP.NET:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615912/asp-net-core-localization-with-json-files
- https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/json-based-localization-in-aspnet-core/